# How to calculate price for mongock professional?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongock

can someone please explain how exactly pricing strategy for mongock professional works?

I can see on this [webpage](https://mongock.io/professional/pricing/) that price is "$20 / unit in production per month", but what is "unit" in this context? Is it single ChangeUnit class? How can I calculate approximate pricing for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the concept of "production units" - this refers to the number of mongodb databases where you are using Mongock as a tool for migration (in production instances). Notice that the minimum is 5 units or production instances.

This means that if you have 3 MongoDB databases in production using Mongock, it would count as 3 units. ChangeUnits are unlimited per database where Mongock is installe.

Notice that Mongock creates a couple of collections/tables in your database - which is the basis for Mongock to operate (and for us to help support with the tool).

Additionally, all environments outside production are free of charge.